# Using Web3.js, how do I call a function on multiple instances of a contract and then store their results in an array?

Tags: web3js, javascript

Using Web3.js, how do I call a function on multiple instances of a contract and then store their results in an array? I've tried .map and .forEach, but they don't return the objects I expected.

I am able to get a desirable result when I call the function on one instance:

```
let giftStats = await SmartGift(
        '0xbb6810057e1D82deE83A981b002F2E0C60293a27'
    )
        .methods.getGiftStats()
        .call()



console.log(giftStats)
```

> `Result {
>    '0': '0xfAA7541C5cBe22E4518736D2b5fC34D07347eE45',
>    '1': '0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000',
>    '2': '0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000',
>    '3': '0',
>    '4': '0',
>    '5': '0',
>    '6': '100',
>    '7': '0',
>    '8': false,
>    '9': false,
>    '10': '' }`

I'm looking for a method that enables me to store two objects like the one above in an array. But when I try to call map() or forEach() on an array of addresses, the resulting array is not what I'd expect.

ATTEMPT 1: .map( )

```
const recipientGifts = ['0xAEaadCd9499127Ae0826aC2E918372927E4B55D4','0xbb6810057e1D82deE83A981b002F2E0C60293a27']    
let giftStats = await recipientGifts.map((address) => {
JSON.stringify(
    SmartGift(address)
    .methods.getGiftStats()
    .call()
)
console.log(giftStats)
```

> [ undefined, undefined ]

ATTEMPT 2: .forEach( )

```
const recipientGifts = ['0xAEaadCd9499127Ae0826aC2E918372927E4B55D4','0xbb6810057e1D82deE83A981b002F2E0C60293a27']  
let giftStats = []
await recipientGifts.forEach((address) =>giftStats.push(SmartGift(address)  
    .methods.getGiftStats() 
    .call() ))
```

console.log(giftStats)

> `[ Promise {
>      _bitField: 0,
>      _fulfillmentHandler0: undefined,
>      _rejectionHandler0: undefined,
>      _promise0: undefined,
>      _receiver0: undefined },
>    Promise {
>      _bitField: 0,
>      _fulfillmentHandler0: undefined,
>      _rejectionHandler0: undefined,
>      _promise0: undefined,
>      _receiver0: undefined } ]`

Answer (score 0):

The second method is pretty close but you should try to put the await inside the forEach since that would return a promise

```
await recipientGifts.forEach(async(address) => giftStats.push(await SmartGift(address)  
    .methods.getGiftStats() 
    .call() ))
```

Comment: I just tried this, but it returns an empty array.

Comment: I think probably forEach doesn't support promises. Just use a normal loop instead, gonna be ok

Comment: Yeah, after incorporating your suggestion, I replaced the .forEach( ) with a for loop, and it works! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I originally wanted to solve this using only functional programming, avoiding loops. But I got it to work using a `for` loop.

```
let giftStats = []
    for (let i = 0; i < recipientGifts.length; i++) {
        giftStats.push(
            await SmartGift(
                recipientGifts[i])
                .methods.getGiftStats()
                .call()
        )
    }
```

console.log(giftStats)
`[ Result {
    '0': '0xfAA7541C5cBe22E4518736D2b5fC34D07347eE45',
    '1': '0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000',
    '2': '0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000',
    '3': '0',
    '4': '0',
    '5': '0',
    '6': '5000',
    '7': '0',
    '8': false,
    '9': false,
    '10': '' },
  Result {
    '0': '0xfAA7541C5cBe22E4518736D2b5fC34D07347eE45',
    '1': '0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000',
    '2': '0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000',
    '3': '0',
    '4': '0',
    '5': '0',
    '6': '100',
    '7': '0',
    '8': false,
    '9': false,
    '10': '' } ]`

Answer (score 0):

A functional way to do this is by combining `Array.map` with `Promise.all`:

```js
const array = await Promise.all(
  recipientGifts.map((address) =>
    SmartGift(address)
      .methods.getGiftStats()
      .call()
);
```